How to copy an object(s) from a large Blender instance to different location in another instance
I have a large scene in a instance/file. I want to copy a few objects from that instance to a new instance but at at a completely different location. When I paste it, perhaps unsurprisingly it is at the same x,y,z coordinates of original source scene.
How can I paste to a specific location? I have tried to use Global Transform Copy but without success, either I am doing it wrong or the two instances dont share the same clipboard which I guess is likely.
I would like to retain the relative positions of the copied objects when as a group they are pasted into the target instance.
Thanks in advance
Larry

Use the "append" command in the "file" menu

Thanks, Daniel, thats a good way to add items to my new instance I wasn't aware of but it works like cut and paste did in the method I've been using. What I need is a method to choose its new location.

A suggestion:

In the original file, add an "empty" object.
Parent every single object to that empty object (ctrl+p -> keep transform)
Import that empty object into the new file
If you want, unparent the items from the "empty" object (alt+p -> keep transform)

